# Redirect to another page after trigger a job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Job that can be trigger using a URL:

```
https://<URL_JENKINS>/view/MY_JOBS/job/BUILD_PROJECT/build?token=secretPassword
```

Its working.
The problem is that after insert this URL in a browser, press Enter, the page stay in a white page forever. It's possible to redirect to another page or the job result page ? I want to add a "user friendly" way to show it.

Answer (score 0):

This request as is will return 201 on a successful request so no redirection will happen.
Either use the Jenkins UI (if you are using the browser anyway) or surround these API calls with some frontend you create so you have power over what happens in the browser when the call is done.